# What metrics would be useful to A/B test site search

Tags: ecommerce, search, a-b-testing

We are trying to implement new type of instant search to our e-commerce. Our present search has lots of filters like price, category, review etc.

What kind of metrics would you use to analyse if it is better or not? I think conversion is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

May be Bounce-Rate. If the new search is quite good, the bounce rate on the search result page would decrease, I think.